# Receiving replies from Outlook even after removing the Outlook channel from MS Bot Framework

Tags: botframework

I created a bot using MS Bot Framework. Then I hooked it up with the Outlook Channel provided by Microsoft Bot Framework.

IT all was working fine and now I decided to remove the channel integration and did so as well. Unfortunately my outlook still replies to mails even after removal of channels. My bots home page on MS shows the below message:

"You haven't connected any channels yet. Select a channel to connect."

I have no clue why I see the replies. Its weird. Please help.

Comment: Please send an email to bf-reports@microsoft.com for assistance

Answer (score 1):

It looks like we have an issue on our side where we are not properly handling the case where you uncheck the "Enable this bot on Email" checkbox. I'll open a bug and get this fixed but in the mean time please use the "Deauthorize" button instead of the checkbox to disable your bot on a channel.